# MySQL create user incorrectly updates user table

Tags: mysql, authentication

I recently upgraded from mysql-community `5.7.4` to `5.7.8`. All packages show the newer version is correctly installed. I reinitialized my database using `mysqld --initialize` and corresponding steps. I then restored from a full dump using the standard method (ie, `zcat dumpfile.gz | mysql`). The server started up fine; I was able to `start slave` and catch up to the master, still running on `5.7.4`. Now the weirdness begins. The user tables don't match. Even if I `stop slave` and restart my mysqld process, the following (and similar) commands do something strange:

```
create user 'test'@'%' identified by 'test334455' ;
```

It puts the hash into the "plugin" field of the user table:

```
mysql> select user,host,password,plugin,authentication_string from user where user='test';
+------+------+----------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
| user | host | password | plugin                                    | authentication_string |
+------+------+----------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
| test | %    |          | *443C443E4789A416587C0A5892C7D345B73B9B3B | NULL                  |
+------+------+----------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
```

To make sure this isn't some weird package-specific bug, I initialized a new database and with a separate mysqld process, verifies the command works as expected. Somehow restoring from a dump or connecting as a slave to an older version causes the problem.

However, *existing* user entries (ones restored from the dump) are *correct* and work just fine.

UPDATE: It appears the `password` field was *removed* between **5.7.5** and **5.7.6**, but the **restore-from-dump** (not replication!) recreated the column; but the current version's `create user` commands still assume a particular order to the columns (** *facepalm* **).

So the Question now is: How do I safely update the master database on 5.7.4 to 5.7.8, preferably without dump/restore?

UPDATE: The Mysql documentation does indeed cover this particular quirk, more or less, on a page well-worth bookmarking (Because really, MySQL, you have no shame in making incompatible changes to sub-minor versions.) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html

Comment: Which databases are you replicating? If you replicate the `mysql` you'll probably run into problems.

Comment: Updated question: it wasn't the replication. It was restoring from dump without doing the `mysql_upgrade`.

Comment: Wow, some bad coding from MySQL there then. Column names should be explicit.

Comment: File a bug at http://bugs.mysql.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mysql_upgrade](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-upgrade.html) is your friend

> mysql_upgrade examines all tables in all databases for
>   incompatibilities with the current version of MySQL Server.
>   mysql_upgrade also upgrades the system tables so that you can take
>   advantage of new privileges or capabilities that might have been
>   added.

Comment: This might be the answer I needed. testing

Comment: Hello @Otheus, were you able to use mysql_upgrade?

Comment: For operational purposes, I had to back out of the upgrade completely, revert to the prior version of MySQL, and do a full rsync from the master. I get to try again soon. Upvoting for now. :)